# Como puedo convertir las claves en indice numérico de un array de javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un array de la siguiente forma:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Inglés", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00", …}
1: {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Computación", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00", …}
2: {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Educación Artística", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00", …}
3: {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Educación Física", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00", …}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Hasta el momento estoy recorriendo los objetos de esta manera

```
for(let i=0;i<response.length;i++){
    console.log(response[i]);
}
```

Pero quiero acceder a las propiedades de la siguiente manera, debido a que columnasTabla, va a ser dinámico, por ejemplo si yo pongo columnasTabla=5, solo me va a imprimir las primeras 5 propiedades de cada objeto

```
for(let i=0;i<response.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<=columnasTabla;i++){
        console.log(response[i][j]);
    }
}
```

en vez de hacerlo por el nombre de la propiedad (response[i].ALUMNO_ID)

Comment: ¿Tú código no hace lo que tú esperas? ¿A qué te refieres con `convertir las claves en índice numérico`? ¿La línea `let j=0;j<=columnasTabla;i++` es correcta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solución 1

Usar [`Object.keys(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys)

> El método `Object.keys()` devuelve un `array` de las propiedades `names` de un objeto, en el mismo orden como se obtienen en un `loop` normal.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let response = [
  {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Inglés", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00"},
  {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Computación", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00"},
  {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Educación Artística", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00"},
  {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Educación Física", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00"}];

// Validar si hay al menos 1 dato para mostrar
let columnas = response.length ? Object.keys(response[0]) : [];
console.log(columnas);

let columnasTabla = columnas.length;

///

for(let i=0;i<response.length;i++){
    // AQUI corregí tuve que cambiar, porque usaba "<=" y "i++" cosa que esta mal
    for(let j=0;j<columnasTabla;j++){
        // AQUI usamos columnas[j] para obtener el nombre de propiedad
        console.log(response[i][columnas[j]]); 
    }
}
```

---

### Solución 2

El problema que veo en la solución anterior, es el caso en el que los objetos traigan mas propiedades de las que se desean imprimir y/o en distinto orden del esperado.

En tal caso podrías **crear un arreglo con el nombre de las propiedades de los objetos en el orden que deben imprimirse** en las columnas.

#### Ejemplo

```js
let response = [
  {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Inglés", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00"},
  {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Computación", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00"},
  {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Educación Artística", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00"},
  {ALUMNO_ID: "1486", GRUPO_ID: "20169", MATERIA: "Educación Física", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1: ".00", CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2: ".00"}];

// AQUI omito la propiedad "GRUPO_ID" porque no deseo imprimirla
let columnas = ['ALUMNO_ID', 'MATERIA', 'CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_1', 'CALIFICACION_BIMESTRE_2'];
let columnasTabla = columnas.length;

///

for(let i=0;i<response.length;i++){
    // AQUI corregí tuve que cambiar, porque usaba "<=" y "i++" cosa que esta mal
    for(let j=0;j<columnasTabla;j++){
        // AQUI usamos columnas[j] para obtener el nombre de propiedad
        console.log(response[i][columnas[j]]); 
    }
}
```

---

**Comentario:** En lo personal creo que la solución 2 es la que deberías implementar para evitar problemas de "*mutaciones*"